# How to get osx shell script to show colors in echo

Tags: macos, bash, shell, echo

I'm trying to add color output to my errors in a bash script that I have running on a mac.  The problem is the colors are not working.  I created the simplest of scripts to demonstrate that it does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\e[1;31m This is red text \e[0m"
```

However, when i run it, I see no colors at all, as shown in this image.  The color output of the ls command is working fine however.

[image]

Comment: I was happy to know that bash was old, and updating it solved my problem.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

OSX ships with an old version of Bash that does not support the `\e` escape character. Use `\x1B` or update Bash (`brew install bash`).

Even better, though, would be to use `tput`.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/bash --version` yields
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

Comment: @nycynik The shipped version of bash was different 46 months before your comment; it was still on 3.x.

Comment: My second comment was the version of bash output after upgrading it .

Comment: Great shout on `tput`

Comment: thanks a lot for explaining why `\e` doesn't work!

Answer (score 117):

Use `\033` or `\x1B` instead of `\e` to represent de `<Esc>` character.

```
echo -e "\033[1;31m This is red text \033[0m"
```

See http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: awesome! many thanks. not sure why its not marked as correct answer

Comment: I think the reason it's not marked as correct - because it does work just fine - is, if you already have scripts that include the `\033` or `\e`, you want to know if you can just use them as they are. And the solution below will enable that.

Answer (score 17):

In script files `printf` could be yet another option, you have to add trailing `"\n"` though.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\e[31mOutput as is.\e[m"
printf "\e[32mThis is green line.\e[m\n"
printf "\e[33;1m%s\n" 'This is yellow bold line.'
```

Tested on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6:

```
% /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option could be using zsh, which respects the `\e` notation.

```
#!/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Starting with macOS Catalina, Macs will now use zsh as the default login shell and interactive shell across the operating system.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote functions from @cu39 answer and used it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

printy() {
  printf "\e[33;1m%s\n" "$1"
}
printg() {
  printf "\e[32m$1\e[m\n"
}
printr() {
  echo -e "\033[1;31m$1\033[0m"
}

printr "This is red"
printy "This is yellow"
printg "This is green"
```

**The result:**

[image]

Comment: It's interesting that each function varies how it works - were you just showing how echo and printf can work?

Comment: @nycynik Not showing anything, just putting it easy to copy and paste for who wants!

Answer (score 3):

A quick exemple of how you can change text color. It's working with many
different version of bash (Mac OS ready also tested on fedora 33 KDE and ubuntu jellyfish gnome).

In this exemple to show you how it work I use `echo`
command with `-e` option to enable interpret backslash escapes and then use
the this part `\x1B[HX;Ym` to start text modification.

```
H for  Highlight option
H = 3 --> Color text       H = 4 --> Highlight text

X for the color
X = 1 --> Red              X = 2 --> Green
X = 3 --> Yellow/orange    X = 4 --> Blue light
X = 5 --> Purple           X = 6 --> Blue dark

Y for the format
Y = 1 --> Bold             Y = 2 --> Normal
Y = 3 --> Italic           Y = 4 --> Underline
```

When you finish text modification use `\x1B[0m`

Try on your terminal :

```
echo -e "Hello my name is \x1B[34;2mVictor\x1B[0m I'm a \x1B[33;2msys-admin\x1B[0m \!\n"
```

https://github.com/victor-sys-admin/MODIFY_TEXT_OUTPUT_COLOR_BASH